# How to change format of date/time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I have this date and time format:

```
2010-05-19 07:53:30
```

and would like to change it to:

```
Wednesday @ 7:53PM 5/19/2010
```

I'm doing this, which gets the current format:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

but when I change the format, I end up with a null.  For example:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm tt MM-dd-yyyy";
date = [formatter stringFromDate:formattedDate];
```

date will be null.  I want to put the end result into an NSString.  It would be nice if time and date could come out as separate properties so I can arrange them however I like.  Any ideas on how I can change the formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your formatting string is the problem. You should only use the characters you find in the table in [UTS#35 Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns). I tried your code and while the time `hh:mm` displays correctly, formatting stops at `tt` - not in the table!

If you really want characters in the format string that are not in the table you can escape them, like `hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz` - produces format like "12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time".

Answer (score 0):

> It would be nice if time and date could come out as separate properties so I can arrange them however I like. Any ideas on how I can change the formatting?

You have things backwards.  If this is a date/time to be displayed to the user, you need to present it how the *user* wants it, not how you want it.  For instance, most people outside the USA will be confused by MM-dd-yyyy particularly if the day is less than 13.  Consider using [-setDateStyle:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBBDBHA) and [-setTimeStyle:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBCJEFC).  That way, the display string will come out as the user expects.