# iPhone SDK Date Format

Tags: iphone, ios, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change format of date/time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871182/how-to-change-format-of-date-time)

In my program I'm making an API call for getting a date, but the received date has an incorrect format. It looks like `2011-07-06 00:00:00`. How I can change it to `6-july-2011`?

Comment: That format is correct. How it is displayed depends on how you format it.

Comment: how can i format in that way.. i tried different things but ended up with null.

Comment: Are you sure you want to put it in a fixed format rather than use the locale of the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try my code that will help you because I run successfully.

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"2011-07-06 00:00:00";
    NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatStr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatStr setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatStr stringFromDate:d];   
    NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-YYYY"];
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```